# Kendo ui wp8 scroll issue

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, scroll, kendo-ui

I write mobile application for wp8 using cordova and kendo ui core.
I have a problem with vertical scroll.
Scroll is slow and freeze. If I use native scroll I have a problem like this:[scroll issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJm6X.png)
This problem occurs on emulator and on device.
And I have question. How can I get good scroll on wp8?

**UPD:** Some code

```
app = new kendo.mobile.Application($(document.body), { layout: 'main-layout', skin: 'flat'});
```

this code Create Kendo App

```
<div data-role="view" id="nextDays" data-title="Прогноз погоды" data-use-native-scrolling="true" data-show="NextDays.show" data-reload="true">
<div id="secondDay">
    <div id="foreHeader2" class="fv-contHeader"><span class="toUpper" data-bind="text: DayOfWeek"></span>,&nbsp;<span data-bind="text: Date"></span></div>
    <div id="night">
        <div class="fv-dayPart">Ночью</div>
        <div class="temp">
            <span data-bind="text: nTemp"></span>
            <span data-bind="attr: {class: nTempTrend}">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="wind">
            <span data-bind="text: nWindSpeed"></span>
            <span data-bind="attr: {class: nWindSpeedTrend}">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="text: nPrec" class="toLower">
        </div>
        <div data-bind="text: nPhen" class="toLower">
        </div>
        <div data-bind="text: nCloud" class="toLower">
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="day">
        <div class="fv-dayPart">Днём</div>
        <div class="temp">
            <span data-bind="text: dTemp"></span>
            <span data-bind="attr: {class: dTempTrend}">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="wind">
            <span data-bind="text: dWindSpeed"></span>
            <span data-bind="attr: {class: dWindSpeedTrend}">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="text: dPrec" class="toLower">
        </div>
        <div data-bind="text: dPhen" class="toLower">
        </div>
        <div data-bind="text: dCloud" class="toLower">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

this is my html. it's my view. `data-use-native-scrolling="true"` enable native scroll and it occurs my problem (see image).

Comment: Can you maybe post some Code?

Comment: Thx. Ok, I added code.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without code.
But try this:
In the config.xml take out:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
```